# What is a loose ball get crumb in AFL?

Tags: terminology, australian-rules-football

I'm facing a file with the records from a game (all that happened in the game: kicks, center bounces, handballs, etc.) and I don't understand the difference between "loose ball get" and "loose ball get crumb" (same for "hard ball get" and "hard ball get crumb"). I am not sure whether this is usual terminology or not.

Comment: Have you read (e.g.) Wikipedia's [Glossary of Australian rules football](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_Australian_rules_football)? That doesn't mean we can't answer this question, but it would be good for you to explain what you don't understand from your research.

Comment: Yes, most of it but I didn't realised there was an entry for crumb. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As @philip-kendall points out in the comments, the answer is in the Wikipedia article [Glossary of Australian rules football](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_Australian_rules_football):

> Loose ball get: a disputed ball at ground level not under direct physical pressure that results in an opportunity to record a legal disposal. Counted as a contested possession.
>
> Crumb: a ball that spills loose from a contest. [...]

So basically the difference is where the handball comes from. For example, if it comes from an ineffective kick it would be a loose/hard ball get. If it comes from a contest where none of the players got it, it would be a loose/hard ball get crumb.